# How to add a space between the words when there is a special character in pyspark dataframe using regex?

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have a dataframe which consists of reviews and has special characters in between the words. I want to add a space.

For example,

Spark)NLP -> Spark ) NLP
Machine-Learning -> Machine - Learning

Below is my dataframe

```
temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "This is 5years of Spark)world 5-6"),
    (1, "I wish Java-DL could use case-classes"),
    (2, "Data-science is  cool"),
    (3, "Machine")
], ["id", "words"])


+---+-------------------------------------+
|id |words                                |
+---+-------------------------------------+
|0  |This is 5years of Spark)world 5-6    |
|1  |I wish Java-DL could use case-classes|
|2  |Data-science is  cool                |
|3  |Machine                              |
+---+-------------------------------------+
```

I have used the below code to do that but it is not working

```
temp_1 = temp.withColumn('words', F.regexp_replace('words', r'(?<! )(?=[.,!?()\/\-\+\'])|(?<=[.,!?()\/\-\+\'])(?! )', '$1 $2 $3'))
```

Desired output:

```
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|id |words                                    |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|0  |This is 5years of Spark ) world 5 - 6    |
|1  |I wish Java - DL could use case - classes|
|2  |Data - science is  cool                  |
|3  |Machine                                  |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[^\w\s]\b|_
```

And replace with  `$0` . See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qp1HsL/1).

If you do not consider an underscore to be a special char, just use `\b[^\w\s]\b` that matches any char other than word and whitespace chars between word chars. Note word chars include underscores.

If there must be letters or digits on each side, replace word boundaries with lookarounds: `(?<=[^\W_])[^\w\s](?=[^\W_])|_`. To only find special chars between letters: `(?<=[^\W\d_])[^\w\s](?=[^\W\d_])|_` or `(?<=\p{L})[^\w\s](?=\p{L})|_`.

Comment: $0 is not working in python. Is there any other option?

Comment: @merkle In Python `re`, it should be `\g<0>`. In Spark, Java regex flavor should work.

Comment: Tried \g<0> but not working. 

temp_1 = temp.withColumn('words', F.regexp_replace('words', r'(\b[^\w\s]\b|_)', '\g<0>'))

Comment: @merkle So, use `$0`, it is Java flavor. If you still have trouble, wrap with the capturing group, `(\b[^\w\s]\b|_)`, and use ``$1`` or ``\1`` with spaces around it.

Comment: @merkle Sure, as I suggested (also, in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qp1HsL/1)). There are spaces around `$0`.